# Connecting to a remote database via a connection string

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I am attempting for my program to read an access database from another computer connected in the same LAN network (intranet). This is the code that I am using:

```
namespace CalUnderFoot
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {    
        CarsDBDataSet dataSet;
        CarsDBDataSetTableAdapters.CarSchedulingTableAdapter adapter;

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data source= \\UNDERFOOT-PC\CalUnderFootDB\CarsDB.mdb"
            };

            con.Open();
             \\do stuff
```

It won't open the database from

```
\\UNDERFOOT-PC\CalUnderFootDB\CarsDB.mdb
```

It only generates another copy of itself in the same location of the program.
I know this is a syntax issue and I am new to C#. So what am I missing here?

I double checked the network connection between the 2 computers and it's OK.

Comment: Try this resource. http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Please try checking the read/write permissions for the **database**, i.e. open it with Access, modify some records and save. If the save operation completed successfully, make sure that **the application** is running under the user which also has **such permissions**.

Comment: Yes I checked all of that! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your connection string does not have credentials.  Have you tried something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
Data Source=\\UNDERFOOT-PC\CalUnderFootDB\CarsDB.mdb;
User Id=admin; Password=;
```

See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2003/

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: Not really an answer to your problem, but I don't have enough reputation to add it as a comment.

Since you say you're new to C#, I assume you don't know about [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx). If you've never heard about it, I think you should check it out. It's a nice abstraction, and spares you of writing in-line SQL.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow really needs to get rid of some of its stupid rules. I am posting this as an answer instead of a comment due to insufficient reputation.

Perhaps [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647%28SQL.90%29.aspx) link may be of help.