# Create Database in C#

Tags: c#, database, connection, localdb, mdf

I am developing an application in C #, which uses a login system. And its needs a database, but until now I did not get anything really clear. I created a localDB file (.mdf) thats needs a connection string which refer to mdf file path. But When a run my app in another pc the connection is never established. But make sense, that connections string refer to my pc mdf file path. How can I make a simple database that created when the app run in any pc? Sorry if my question is very noob, I'm new at it and didn't found nothing related. thanks to everyone!

Comment: Does this database need to be shared by each installation of the application or are the logins local to each separate installation?

Comment: Connecting to Access remotely...  Maybe this might help: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072552/connecting-to-a-remote-database-via-a-connection-string)

Comment: @cChacon localdb and .mdf is not MS Access.

Comment: @Adolfok3 Duh!  You're right!  So, what are you using?  SQL Server, SQL Server Compact?

Comment: I dont know what to use, I looking for something like sqlite in android. Just instal a simple database when run my app in any pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using some flavour of file based database with your app, then your connection string should be made to refer to a path on the local machine, rather than some sort of network path/path to another machine.

If the path you store your db in exhibits some aspect that will never/shouldn't exist on another machine (such as something not relevant to the foreign machine like c:\users\yourusername\documents..) then you need to move your database to somewhere more "expected" (like alongside your exe) and adjust your connectionstring path accordingly. Also, make sure the destination machine has the requisite database technology installed (e.g. LocalDB)

Comment: Theres no way to create a simple database when run my app? Something like Sqlite in android.

Comment: SQLite exists for windows too, but we can only answer the question as asked, and I didn't understand it to be "what small embedded db options do I have for a windows app" - perhaps you need to think more about what your question actually is? Is this database only for logins? It perhaps doesn't need an sql based db technology at all.. even a flat text file will do

Comment: I think a xml database can solve my problem, but is more  complicated than a simple database with default querys. The initial idea was that, an app that's need to store some informations in a database, which create it programmatically.